# How to share links to different pages on iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, hyperlink, tabs, sharing

I have an iframe tab which holds php page with various links inside (like "News", "Photos" etc.). Is it possible to generate a facebook link which leads directly to certain link inside the iframe? By facebook link I mean link that will keep you on facebook, open your iframe tab and view certain page on that iframe. The thing is that all I can do now is to link only to my iframe tab which has address like http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_someid. Then I will land on my default page tab url. But I want to land on different one. Any tips on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an app_data parameter to the tab URL is passed back to your application as part of the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter  in FB's post call to include your content. Use that parameter after de-signing it to then decide what to show and what not to.

Your URLs will become like:

> http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_someid?app_data=showViewX
>   http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_someid?app_data=showViewY

and then in your code:

```
// Get Signed Request
$app_data = $signed_request['app_data'];
if($app_data === "showViewX") {
  // Show one view
} else {
  // show others..
}
```

Currently, the app_data param is not sent if the user just liked the page when he lands on it with an app_data param. The bug on FB has been filed at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/172963266154996 and we are all hoping for an early resolution.